# RavenDb Authorization + SOA

Tags: authorization, soa, ravendb

The question I have is that of securing documents across services using RavenDb and the Authorization bundle:

I have an 'Account' service which is responsible for managing all things 'user'.

I have a 'Messaging' service which is responsible for all things 'messaging' i.e. wall posts, conversations etc.

To trace who did what in this service, when a new message is posted I create the message and two UserProxy objects (cut down User objects which only have UserId and UserName properties - these are stored as child objects on the WallPost doc so they aren't documents in their own right)

When a user posts something to another users wall i only want to allow:

- delete/edit to the original poster, the recipient and admins
- view to original poster, recipient, admins and all friends of the recipient

I also have a media service which is responsible for images/video,  a MusicEvent service for all things music event - they all need to have a similar setup.

My question is this:

*should the account service store the master User with Roles and Permissions - when it is asked for a user it can send back a dto with the roles and permissions (could get chunky)

*should the Messaging Service maintain it's own copy of a User - with it's own set of roles and permissions?

first is simpler moving forward as it's centralised - but looks a bit dodgy to me
second is probably better but the issue comes when the AccountService changes the username - i can send an event to the esb and have all the relevant services pick it up and take care of the update - but that sounds complicated.

FTR - i'm swaying to option 2 - the non-centralised method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ayende answered this for me quite nicely on his blog:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/02/17/distributed-authorization-with-ravendb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would think about introducing a third service - e.g. IT / Administration service that would be responsible for Roles and Permissions. Its strikes me that these are different business functions / capabilities to those described in Account or Messaging services. A service responsible for that type of functionality would decouple the security aspects of your services from the actual functional areas of Accounts and Messaging. Accounts could still remain the *owner* of Account information. The messaging service really only needs to identify the user and so using user id / username here is sufficient, unless it nees aditional user information to do its work (email address perhaps). Its ok to duplicate data in this instance, as long as Accounts remains the owner of information.